# RTSP Command to Request Camera for Current FPS

Tags: camera, rtsp, frame-rate

In my RTSP server, i need to know what is the current fps of the stream from Axis Camera every second.

is there any specific RTSP Command through which i can request camera to send FPS information to RTSP server..??

Thanks,

Prateek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only official way in RTSP to inform a receiver about the frame rate is inside the SDP of the DESCRIBE response.

Either directly via `a=framerate:<frame rate>` which gives by definition only the maximum frame rate. Or inside the configuration information of your stream which shall also sent via SDP in `a=rtpmap:<payload type> <encoding name>/<clock rate> [/<encoding parameters>]` or regularly inside the stream.

A better way is to compute the frame rate on your receiver side by using the timestamp of every incoming frame.

Most newer AXIS-devices (those using H.264) using the absolute Timestamp of the camera (check the camera setup!) The firmware of the older devices is buggy and you can not rely on the timestamp sent by the camera - only on the time-difference of two frames are exact.

jens.